# php include not showing latest data

Tags: php, html

I have a button on my page that executes a .sh script which writes to connection_check.txt. The issue I'm running into is that after the script has ran, the old version/data is still shown on the page as it doesn't seem the page gets fully refreshed after the .sh has ran so the old data is still cached. Or maybe its because I have $_SESSION set because apart from write to a file, the .sh also echos a value that unhides the divs.

I'm very unfamiliar with html and php. My div looks like this.

```
<div class="connection_details" id="connection_details_id" style="display:none;">
<p><?php include('connection_check.txt'); ?></p>
</div>
```

I also tried adding this to no avail..

```
<?php if ($output1 == 1) : ?>
<script>
document.getElementById("connection_details_id").style.display = "block";
</script>
$("#connection_details_id").load(location.href + " #connection_details_id");
<?php endif ?>
```

How can I make sure connection_check.txt is retrieved again after running the .sh and changing style.display to block??

Comment: It does not work like that. You have to write a script that gets data from the server after pressing the button. You can't include a `php` file after the response is sent.

Comment: Write JavaScript and PHP separately

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution myself.

```
<?php if ($output1 == 1) : ?>
<script src="jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$("#connection_details_id").load('connection_check.txt')
</script>
<script>
document.getElementById("connection_details_id").style.display = "block";
</script>
<?php endif ?>
```

Might not be pretty but it works.

Comment: You don't have to end the script tag if you are about to open it again `</script><script>`

Comment: Attach a random string to `connection_check.txt` to avoid browser cache, as shown in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, How do you run the .sh script, However run the following code after you run it

```
$("#connection_details_id").load("connection_check.txt?val=" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 101) );
```

Also, take a look at [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp)